# Partial derivative of two variable function: $f(x,y)=\frac{2x^3-3y^2}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

What is the partial derivatives  of this function at the point $(0,0)$?

$$f(x,y)=
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{2x^3-3y^2}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if }(x,y)\ne(0,0) \\
    0 & \text{if }(x,y)=(0,0)
  \end{cases}
$$

Thanks.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I use the definition of derivatives at (0,0).
df/dx = lim (f(0+h)-f(0)/h) when h approches to zero. that implies lim(2h^3/h^3) as h approches to 0 equal to 2. 
In the same way, I found that df/dy at (0,0) is 3.
Am I right?

Comment: How did you end up with $h^3$ in the denominator?

Comment: I'm so sorry.It was my mistake. df/dy at (0,0) is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \begin{cases}
f_x(0,0): \lim_{h\to0} f(h,0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2h^3}{h^3}=2 \implies f_x(0,0)=2\\f_y(0,0): \lim_{h\to0} f(0,h)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-3h^2}{h^3}=\pm\infty \implies f_y(0,0) \quad N.D.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I don't know about JMath that's why I type my solution like this. I use the derivative definition and df/dx= lim ((f(0+h,0)-f(0))/h as h approaches zero equals to lim ( 2(h)^3)/(h)^3 as h approaches zero is 2. As the same way we can find df/dy=lim(f(0,0+h)-f(0))/h as h approches zero is lim ((-3)/h) when h approches zero in infinite.

Comment: That’s correct, thus we say that $f_y(0,0)$ does not exist in (0,0).It is like $g(x)=\sqrt x$ for which is not derivable in 0 since $g’(x)=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt x}$.